# Use apply to replace multiple values in a dataframe

Tags: r, apply

I want to use apply to replace values in a dataframe, if >8 1 star, if >10 2 stars, if >12 3 stars, else NS.

```
mydata<-data.frame(A=1:10, B=3:12, C=5:14)
apply(mydata, 2, function(x) ifelse(x > 12, "***"|x > 10, "**"|x >= 8, "*"|x <8, "NS", x))
```

Comment: Don't use `apply(... MARGIN = 2, ...)` on data frames. Use `lapply` instead. `apply` is made for matrices (or when you want to `apply` to data frame rows, which means converting the df to a matrix first).

Comment: just curious, an extension of this question could be, how to solve this problem using tidyverse or data.table syntax?

Comment: @ManishSaraswat, you can use Florian's answer like `mydata %>% mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(x > 12, "***", ifelse(x >= 10, "**", ifelse(x >= 8, "*", "NS"))))` or `setDT(mydata)[, (names(mydata)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x > 12, "***", ifelse(x >= 10, "**", ifelse(x >= 8, "*", "NS"))))]`. But why bother? I suspect Florian's answer is the fastest and most straightforward compared to a `data.table` or `tidyverse` implementation.

Comment: Text an code are not consistent: in the text you write *if >8 1 star* but in the code you state `|x >= 8, "*"|` For the value 8 the result is not clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that to use nested `ifelse` statements, you need to put the next `ifelse` as the third argument (the `else` argument) in the parent `ifelse`. So you could try the following:

```
ifelse(mydata > 12, "***", ifelse(mydata >= 10, "**", ifelse(mydata >= 8, "*", "NS")))
```

Output:

```
      A    B    C    
 [1,] "NS" "NS" "NS" 
 [2,] "NS" "NS" "NS" 
 [3,] "NS" "NS" "NS" 
 [4,] "NS" "NS" "*"  
 [5,] "NS" "NS" "*"  
 [6,] "NS" "*"  "**" 
 [7,] "NS" "*"  "**" 
 [8,] "*"  "**" "**" 
 [9,] "*"  "**" "***"
[10,] "**" "**" "***"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

A `tidyverse` alternative with `case_when`:

```
mydata %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(case_when(. > 12 ~ '***',
                            . > 10 & . <= 12 ~ '**',
                            . >= 8 & . <= 10 ~ '*',
                            . < 8 ~ 'NS')))
```

which gives:

> ```
>     A  B   C
> 1  NS NS  NS
> 2  NS NS  NS
> 3  NS NS  NS
> 4  NS NS   *
> 5  NS NS   *
> 6  NS  *   *
> 7  NS  *  **
> 8   *  *  **
> 9   * ** ***
> 10  * ** ***
> ```

Answer (score 4):

This is not a place you need to use apply, just select rows using bracket notation:

```
ns <- mydata < 8
s3 <- mydata > 12
s2 <- mydata > 10 & mydata <= 12
s1 <- mydata >= 8 & mydata <= 10

mydata[ns] <- 'NS'
mydata[s3] <- '***'
mydata[s2] <- '**'
mydata[s1] <- '*'
```

NOTE: the conditional statements have to be before the assignment because once you assign a character value to any cell in a column, that column is converted from `numeric` to `character` and future conditional statements will use lexicographic comparison (1 < a < b < c < A) rather than numeric comparison.

Comment: Glad that's fixed, but at this point I would say it's a more awkwardly coded version of the `cut` answer. Does work though.

Comment: You could replace the values with `mydata[] <- c('NS','*','**','***')[ns + (2*s1) + (3*s2) + (4*s3)]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cut` and set the labels:

```
mydata<-data.frame(A=1:10, B=3:12, C=5:14)
as.data.frame(lapply(mydata, function(x) cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 8, 10, 12, Inf), labels = c("NS","*","**","***"))))
# A  B   C
# 1  NS NS  NS
# 2  NS NS  NS
# 3  NS NS  NS
# 4  NS NS  NS
# 5  NS NS   *
# 6  NS NS   *
# 7  NS  *  **
# 8  NS  *  **
# 9   * ** ***
# 10  * ** ***
```

Comment: You should use lower limits, `c(-inf,7,10,12,inf)` as the breaks.

Comment: @Onyambu Then the result for the value 10 would not be correct.

Comment: @jogo why would it not be correct? this would break down as `(-Inf,7],(7,10],(10,12],(12,Inf)`. So 10 is in the bracket of between 8 and 10 inclusive

Comment: My issue with setting the break at 7 is, if there are real numbers then  `(7,8]` is not classified appropriately. To me the break should be 8-`r's precision`

Comment: @Onyambu you arre right: for 10 it will be correct, but not for a value, e.g. `7.5`

Answer (score 2):

```
ifelse(mydata >= 8 & mydata <= 10, "*",
         ifelse(mydata > 10 & mydata <= 12, "**", 
                ifelse(mydata > 12, "***", "NS" )))
      A    B    C    
 [1,] "NS" "NS" "NS" 
 [2,] "NS" "NS" "NS" 
 [3,] "NS" "NS" "NS" 
 [4,] "NS" "NS" "*"  
 [5,] "NS" "NS" "*"  
 [6,] "NS" "*"  "*"  
 [7,] "NS" "*"  "**" 
 [8,] "*"  "*"  "**" 
 [9,] "*"  "**" "***"
[10,] "*"  "**" "***"
```

Comment: @jogo, the result is correct, see OP's defition: " if >8 1 star, if >10 2 stars, if >12 3 stars, else NS", therefore for value = 8, 'NS' should be returned.

Comment: `if >8 1 star` it does not have `=`.